# Unable to install cx_Oracle in pypy3

Tags: python-3.6, cx-oracle, pypy

When I am trying to install cx_Oracle on pypy3, I am getting the below error message:

```
==========================================================================================

  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/e3/cfd4f413f8d47dd2aee09273d9bb3ee6aa7384e0a04e191d703c2199eb93/cx_Oracle-7.3.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: cx-Oracle
  Running setup.py install for cx-Oracle ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\ANAND_RA\Downloads\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\pypy3.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ANAND_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ad2wy
'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ANAND_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z5uxsatb\install-r
         cwd: C:\Users\ANAND_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ad2wywdp\cx-Oracle\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'cx_Oracle' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\ANAND_RA\Downloads\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\pypy3.6-v7.3.0-win32\pypy3.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ANAND_~1\\AppDat
.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ANAND_~1\AppData\Local\T
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

=====================================================================================================
```

Below are the versions if Python and pypy3 in my machine:

Python 3.6.9 (1608da62bfc7, Dec 23 2019, 12:38:24)
[PyPy 7.3.0 with MSC v.1911 32 bit]

I tried to search for a solution to overcome this error message. However, I couldn't find any. So, asking this as a new question.
Thanks,
Anand

Comment: Do you have a microsoft compiler on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install visual studio:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Please refer:
https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html

Comment: Hi Summit/mattip, I added following components from Visual Studio 2017: Static analysis tools
.NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK
.NET Framework 4.6.1 targeting pack
ClickOnce Publishing
NuGet package manager
TypeScript 3.1 SDK
Visual Studio C++ core features
Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable Update
VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)
Windows Universal CRT SDK
Windows 8.1 SDK
C++/CLI support
VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop
Testing tools core features
NuGet targets and build tasks. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: After installing the below components, I restarted my machine and was able to install cx_Oracle on pypy3: Static analysis tools
,.NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK
,.NET Framework 4.6.1 targeting pack
,ClickOnce Publishing
,NuGet package manager
,TypeScript 3.1 SDK
,Visual Studio C++ core features
,Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable Update
,VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
,Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)
,Windows Universal CRT SDK
,Windows 8.1 SDK
,C++/CLI support
,VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop
,Testing tools core features
,NuGet targets and build tasks